# Using popen to read and write in C using two executables

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, popen

I understand that `popen` doesn't allow simultaneous read and write.

To get around this, I created two files, `1.c` for writing, and `2.c` for reading. The files are included below.

When I run `1.out`, I get the expected output on `stdout`:

```
bodhi@bodhipc:~/Downloads$ ./1.out
Stockfish 11 64 BMI2 by T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott
bodhi@bodhipc:~/Downloads$
```

However, `2.out` doesn't give any output on `stdout`:

```
bodhi@bodhipc:~/Downloads$ ./2.out
bodhi@bodhipc:~/Downloads$
```

Where am I going wrong?

**1.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{    
  FILE *fp;
  char path[1035];

  /* Open the command for writing. */
  fp = popen("./stockfish", "w");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

  fprintf(fp,"uci\n");

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

**2.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *fp;
  char path[1035];

  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("./1.out", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it.*/
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), stdout) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
    printf("Done!\n");
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), stdout) != NULL) {
```

you don't want to read from `stdout`, instead:

```
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
```